# CastException with Java NIO sockets

Tags: java, class, sockets, nio

I've been studying the book `Pro Java 7 NIO.2` to get a better understanding of the NIO package, and wanted to work on some networking related code to better my understanding of how netty works in the background. The over-all error makes sense, but why the error is being thrown is beyond my comprehension.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.SocketChannel
```

The first thing that I did was make sure that none of my code was importing anything from the sun packaging, and that everything was in-fact using the java.nio package. Everything seems to check out.

**This error is thrown when** I attempt to connect a client to the server, but what really bothers me is the general fact that it's trying to type-cast to a ServerSocketChannel and not just a SocketChannel, which leads me to believe that the Server is confused.

I do apologise in advance for a wall of code down below, but as everyone always requests that I post a running example I plan to do just that. This is three class files small.

**TcpProcessor.java**

```
package net.ogserver.proto.tcp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;

import net.ogserver.proto.connections.Connection;


public class TcpProcessor implements Runnable {

    public static int tcpPort;

    public void run() {
        try (Selector selector = Selector.open();
                ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open()) { 
            if((serverSocket.isOpen()) && (selector.isOpen())) {
                serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
                serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(tcpPort));
                serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
                System.out.println("Server has started and is waiting for connections...");
                while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    selector.select();
                    Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                    while(keys.hasNext()) {
                        SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();
                        keys.remove();
                        if(!key.isValid()) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if(key.isAcceptable()) {
                            processIncomingConnection(key, selector);
                        } else if(key.isReadable()) {
                            //processIncomingData(key);
                        } else if(key.isWritable()) {
                            //pushOutgoingData(key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("There was an issue constructing the socket.");
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processIncomingConnection(SelectionKey selectionKey, Selector selector) throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = (ServerSocketChannel)selectionKey.channel();
        SocketChannel       clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        clientSocket.configureBlocking(false);

        System.out.println("Incoming connection from " + clientSocket.getRemoteAddress());

        selectionKey.attach(new Connection(selectionKey));

        clientSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
}
```

**Connection.java**

```
package net.ogserver.proto.connections;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Connection {

    private SelectionKey    selectionKey;
    private SocketChannel   clientSocket;

    private ByteBuffer      networkInputBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer      networkOutputBuffer;

    public Connection(SelectionKey selectionKey) {
        this.selectionKey = selectionKey;
        this.clientSocket = (SocketChannel)selectionKey.channel();
        this.networkInputBuffer     = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        this.networkOutputBuffer    = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
    }

    public SelectionKey getSelectionKey() {
        return selectionKey;
    }

    public ByteBuffer getInputBuffer() {
        return networkInputBuffer;
    }

    public ByteBuffer getOutputBuffer() {
        return networkOutputBuffer;
    }

    public SocketChannel getChannel() {
        return clientSocket;
    }

}
```

**Server.java**

```
package net.ogserver.proto;

import net.ogserver.proto.tcp.TcpProcessor;


public class Server {

    private Thread tcpProcessor;

    public Server(int port) {
        TcpProcessor.tcpPort = port;
        tcpProcessor = new Thread(new TcpProcessor());
        tcpProcessor.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server(5055);
    }
}
```

There error occurs when `TcpProcessor#processIncomingConnection` is called, which invokes the creation of a new `Connection` instance. The line throwing this error is a direct quote from the book, and I've taken a look at a few other NIO servers and the line is exactly the same (Minus some naming) in most of them.

```
this.clientSocket = (SocketChannel)selectionKey.channel();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, full console output for those who want it:

```
Server has started and is waiting for connections...
Incoming connection from /127.0.0.1:53221
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.SocketChannel
    at net.ogserver.proto.connections.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:17)
    at net.ogserver.proto.tcp.TcpProcessor.processIncomingConnection(TcpProcessor.java:60)
    at net.ogserver.proto.tcp.TcpProcessor.run(TcpProcessor.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I should probably add that the implementation of typecasting socketchannel form the selectionkey.channel() comes straight from the JavaDocs -- http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/09/04/nio.html?page=2

Comment: Having a look at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl source, it seems it extends java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel and implements sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl, but there seems to be no relation with java.nio.channels.SocketChannel

Comment: @hammerfest - The strangest issue and the most boggling of all is that this only occurs when I connect a client locally. (This client is on the same machine as the server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the wrong `SelectionKey` to `new Connection(...)`. You're passing the server socket's key. The key you should pass is the accepted socket's key, which is the result of `socketChannel.register()`, on the next line.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering where I was going wrong. This got everything working perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

The sun.nio.ch.* classes appear to contain some implementations of interfaces in the java.nio.* package(s); the crossover to the different package occurs in the implementation classes you're using.  No great mystery there.

By looking at the source for sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl, I see that it implements java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel, not java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.  It's a channel implementation, not a socket implementation.  Both the ServerSocketChannel and SocketChannel (in java.nio.channels) extend AbstractSelectableChannel, but they are siblings in the inheritance hierarchy, not ancestor/descendant.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this is that the ServerSocketChannel is comming from the `SelectionKey` when I make a local connection, however if I make a remote connection (from a computer across the network in which the server is not running) it registers as a SocketChannel like it should and continues the process of server/client communication.

Comment: Will casting to AbstractSelectableChannel do what you want?  I'm not familiar with the java.nio socket classes, so I'm just taking a shot in the dark here.  The point is that both the classes you say you can end up with extend that one. I'm afraid I cannot explain why the two classes have common methods (bind, socket, accept) that are not defined in the abstract class -- seems to me it would be what one would want.

Comment: @arcy No it wouldn't. He will need to read and write with it. And they don't both have `accept()` methods.